# DataJS Rendering Date as /Date(1363708765000)/

Tags: date, sharepoint-2010, datajs

I am accessing the SharePoint 2010 List WCF data service via DataJS and getting back date fields as `/Date(1363708765000)/` does anyone have any idea how I can process this to display a proper date?

Note: I am posing here as I suspect this is a DataJS question more than a peculiarity of the `ListData.svc` in SharePoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're receiving back is a [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which represents the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since Jan. 01 1970. Fortunately, JavaScript also uses this as its epoch, meaning you can create a new Date object using elapsed milliseconds as your input parameter:

```
var myDate = new Date(1363708765000);
console.log("UTC:" + myDate.toUTCString());
// outputs UTC: Tue, 19 Mar 2013 15:59:25 GMT
```

Of course, you'll have to parse out the integer portion of the date value you're getting back before you can use it to initialize a date. A reusable function might look like this:

```
function parseJsonDate( sDate ) {
    var b, e, i;
    b = sDate.indexOf('(');
    e = sDate.indexOf(')');
    i = sDate.substring(b+1,e);

    if (isNaN(i)) { return null };
    return new Date(parseInt(i));
}
```